# Multistore Setup in different directory with custom layout in Magento

Tags: magento

Consider the example I have 2 stores with one magento install say A & B. I have 2 different custom themes for Store A & B Ex. themeA & themeB respectively. I have followed the Procedure to creating the stores & the sub folder will contain only 2 files index.php & .htaccess and made the changes into the index.php file.

Now I put both the themes themeA & themeB under directory-
magento/app/design/frontend/default/

Similarly skin files of both themes will go under directory -
magento/skin/frontend/default/

Once this is done go to admin > system >configuration. Here look in the left side bar at the top you will find the current configuration scope dropdown which will list all your stores select store A from drop down, magento will refesh the page & will load all the configuration for that particular store. Then select design tab in left tabs > go to theme section & save theme name which say themeA. Here unchecked “use default” or “use website” checkbox as per your configuration. so it will apply the theme to store. Apply same procedure for 2nd store.

the problem is that every time when i run the storeA or B it is loading the same layout.
Please help me how can be i able to load different layout for the different stores.

Thanks
Rangnath

Comment: Would you add to your question code snippets how do you load A & B stores in both index.php files?

Comment: Did you enter the theme name in the admin under the section Themes?

Comment: Yes i have enter the theme name in admin under the theme section but its loading only one theme.

Answer (score 0):

Create your themes themeA & themeB under directory- magento/app/design/frontend/

Similarly skin files of both themes will go under directory - magento/skin/frontend/

Now go to Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Change your current configuration scope -> Click on design tab -> Change your current package name.

[image]

Then clear your cache and check.